# C++ : istringstream conversion to long int doesn't work

Tags: c++, string, istringstream

My problem is, I want to convert a string into a long int. For that, i use an istringstream that way:

```
long x;
string lString;
istringstream istr;
getLine(cin, lString);
istr.str(lString);
if(!(istr>>x)) return false; //Edited after answer below
```

(the conversion and the cin are actually in two different methods, I just put the related code together).

The following code returns false if I type "1", but not if I type "1.0". I could search for . in the string and add it if ther isn't, but isn't there a method to convert string to long ?

Comment: Why'd you do that anyway? Use [`std::stol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) instead.

Comment: Problem with that is it raises an exception instead of returning false if the conversion didn't work. I have to know if the string is "invalid" but I don't want the program to stop, and we didn't learn the exception mecanisms yet (it's a practical work for school) so I guess we're not expected to use them. I didn't know about this though, and I may use it anyway, so, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The `!` operator has higher precedence than the `>>` operator, so for the compiler what you have written is

```
if ((!istr) >> x)
```

You need to add your own parentheses:

```
if (!(istr >> x))
```

Comment: Sorry, I copied the one time I got it wrong (and you helped correcting another mistake, thanks^^. But that problem happens with the parentheses at the right place :s